# c++ insert to a stream with formatting for hex

Tags: c++, hex

I often do something like:

```
uint8_t c=some_value;
std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2);
std::cout << std::hex << int(c);
std::cout << std::setfill(' ');
```

(in particular while dumping debugging information). Wouldn't it be nice to have something manipulatorish that I could put in a stream like this:

std::cout << "c value: 0x" << hexb(c) << '\n';

that would do all of that?  Does anyone know how to do that?

I've gotten this to work but would love to have a simpler way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
class hexcdumper{
public:
    hexcdumper(uint8_t c):c(c){};
    std::ostream&
    operator( )(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        // set fill and width and save the previous versions to be restored later
        char fill=os.fill('0');
        std::streamsize ss=os.width(2);

        // save the format flags so we can restore them after setting std::hex
        std::ios::fmtflags ff=os.flags();

        // output the character with hex formatting
        os  << std::hex << int(c);

        // now restore the fill, width and flags
        os.fill(fill);
        os.width(ss);
        os.flags(ff);
        return os;
    }
private:
    uint8_t c;
};

hexcdumper
hexb(uint8_t c)
{
    // dump a hex byte with width 2 and a fill character of '0'
    return(hexcdumper(c));
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const hexcdumper& hcd)
{    
   return(hcd(os)); 
}
```

When I do this:

```
std::cout << "0x" << hexb(14) << '\n';
```

1. hexb(c) is invoked and returns a hexcdumper whose constructor saves c
2. the overloaded operator<< for hexcdumper invokes
   hexcdumper::operator() passing it the stream
3. hexcdumper's operator() does all the magic for us
4. after hexcdumper::operator() returns, the overloaded operator<<
   returns the stream  as returned from hexcdumper::operator() so chaining works.

On the output, I see:

```
0x0e
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Patrick

Comment: What's wrong with your solution you think? Looks fine for me, and if it does what you want. **Elegance** is overated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly on the stream pipe:

```
std::cout << "Hex = 0x" << hex << 14 << ", decimal = #" << dec << 14 << endl;
```

Output:

```
Hex = 0xe, decimal = #14
```

Comment: That's true, but doesn't set the fill or width appropriately, nor restore them afterword without a lot of verbosity.  The question was just about how to avoid the repetitive verbosity.  Instead of your 0xe, I'd prefer 0x0e, or if I was doing this with a string stream outputting bytes of 3, 7, and 14, I'd prefer 03070e to 37e which would be confusing and arguably wrong.  With the solution I've come up with so far, it works fine with a string stream as well.